# powerful geojson editor to edit 10MB worth of .geojson data

Tags: editor, geojson

alright, I have a geojson file that is about 10MB, normal browser based editors fail for obvious reasons, so is there any geojson editor that is powerful enough to edit a 10MB file? and I am not talking about just a JSON editor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I made in the past good experience with https://vector.rocks/.
It is an online GeoJSON editor that can work with large files. Disadvantageous is the limited functionality of the tool.

I would also check if you really need a 10MB file.
Depending on your application it might be worth compressing the file to make it easier to work with.
At https://mapshaper.org/ you can load a GeoJSON file (even very large files) and download it with reduced size but lower precision.

If both solutions are not suitable for you, you will probably have to get used to a professional GIS software.
Some of the most popular free softwares are:

- QGIS (https://qgis.org)
- gvSIG (http://www.gvsig.com/en/products/gvsig-desktop)
- GRASS (https://grass.osgeo.org/)

They all can easily deal with 10MB files but it will but it will take you some time until you are used to the editing functions.

Answer (score -1):

While designed for editing OSM, I find JOSM to also be a powerful desktop editor for large geoJSON files:

https://josm.openstreetmap.de/

You'll just want to be careful working with polygons, because JOSM doesn't directly support geoJSON polygons – they instead used a "closed way" linestring, but there is a patch:

https://josm.openstreetmap.de/ticket/17453

https://josm.openstreetmap.de/ticket/18902

Beyond polygons, JOSM is well suited for working with geoJSON linestrings and points